# How to apply Fixpoint definitions within proofs in Coq?

Tags: coq

I have some trouble understanding how to use some of the things I've defined in Coq within proofs. I have this fragment of definition and functions:

```
Inductive string : Set :=
| E  : string
| s  : nat -> string -> string.

Inductive deduce : Set :=
|de : string -> string -> deduce.

Infix "|=" := de. 

Inductive Rules : deduce -> Prop :=
| compress : forall (n   : nat) (A    : string), rule (( s n ( s n A))  |= ( s n A))
 | transitive : forall A B C : string, rule (A |= B) -> rule (B |= C) -> rule (A |= C).

Fixpoint RepString (n m : nat): string:=
match n with  
|0 => E
|S n => s m ( RepString n m)
end.
```

I need to prove something apparently easy but I bump into two problems:

```
Lemma LongCompress (C : string)(n : nat): n >=1 -> Rules 
((RepString n 0 ) |= (s 0 E) ).
Proof.
intros.
induction n.
inversion H.
simpl.
apply compress.
```

So here I have problem one, I get:

```
"Unable to unify "Rules (s ?M1805 (s ?M1805 ?M1806) |= s ?M1805 ?M1806)" with 
"Rules (s 0 (RepString n 0) |- s 0 E)".'"
```

Now, I can see why I get the error, while technically `RepString n 0` is the same as  `s 0 (s 0 (s 0( ... s 0 E)))` I simply can't find the way to let coq know that, I've tried messing with `apply compress with` like 10 different things I still can't get it right. I need to "unfold" it something like that (of course `unfold` doesn't work...).

I'm out of ideas and I would very much appreciate any input you have on this!

EDIT FROM NOW ON.

```
Inductive Rules : deduce -> Prop :=
| compress : forall (n   : nat) (A    : string), rule (( s n ( s n A))  |= ( s n A))
 | transitive : forall A B C : string, rule (A |= B) -> rule (B |= C) -> rule (A |= C)
 | inspection : forall (n m : nat) (A    : string), m < n -> rule ((s n A) |- (s m A)).

 Definition less (n :nat )  (A B : string) :=  B |= (s n A).
 Lemma oneLess (n m : nat):  rule (less 0 (RepString n 1) (RepString m 1)) <-> n< m.
```

I have generalised the lemmas that Anton Trunov helped me prove, but now I bumped into another wall. I think the problem might start with the way I've written the Theorem itself, I will appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd prove something a little bit more general: for any two non-empty strings of zeros s = `0000...0` and t = `00...0`, if `length s > length t`, then `s |= t`, i.e.

```
forall n m,
  m <> 0 ->
  n > m -> 
  Rules (RepString n 0 |= RepString m 0).
```

Here is a helper lemma:

```
Require Import Coq.Arith.Arith.
Require Import Coq.omega.Omega.
Hint Constructors Rules.  (* add this line after the definition of `Rules` *)

Lemma LongCompress_helper (n m k : nat):
  n = (S m) + k ->
  Rules (RepString (S n) 0 |= RepString (S m) 0).
Proof.
  generalize dependent m.
  generalize dependent n.
  induction k; intros n m H.
  - Search (?X + 0 = ?X). rewrite Nat.add_0_r in H.
    subst. simpl. eauto.
  - apply (transitive _ (RepString n 0) _); simpl in H; rewrite H.
    + simpl. constructor.
    + apply IHk. omega.
Qed.
```

Now, we can easily prove our advertised general lemma:

```
Lemma LongCompress_general (n m : nat):
  m <> 0 ->
  n > m -> 
  Rules (RepString n 0 |= RepString m 0).
Proof.
  intros Hm Hn. destruct n.
  - inversion Hn.
  - destruct m.
    + exfalso. now apply Hm.
    + apply LongCompress_helper with (k := n - m - 1). omega.
Qed.
```

It's easy to see that any sufficiently long string of zeros can be compressed into the singleton-string `0`:

```
Lemma LongCompress (n : nat):
  n > 1 -> Rules ( RepString n 0  |= s 0 E ).
Proof.
  intro H. replace (s 0 E) with (RepString 1 0) by easy.
  apply LongCompress_general; auto.
Qed.
```

Comment: Ho @"Anton Trunov", thank you for your answer. I didn't write that I also have a transitive rule, but I've added it now. So they idea in words is "if the first and second element of a string are the same, I can delete one of the occurrences". In numbers: `0000 |= 000 |= 00 |=0`. Could you please give me some hint as to how to write the lemma the right way? I'm failing to see how to fix it :(

Comment: @"Anton Trunov", Thank you for updating  this, it helps me see things better, but I have a couple of questions, specially with the helper. Why do we need Search and what exactly is it doing? I've tried looking for it but the explanations didn't help me much. What does the + and - do on a proof? I had never seen them and I want to learn more about it all! And my last question, when I get to the part of `apply (transitive _ (RepString n 0) _)` I get an error that "n" is not on the environment, I feel like I'm missing something here o.O Thank you again for your help!

Comment: @Sara **(1)** `Search` is a vernacular command (it's not a tactic), that helps you find a lemma according to some pattern (it searches in the current context, like imported modules, current file's definitions, etc.). In this case I wanted to rewrite `S m + 0` to `S m`, and that's what `Nat.add_0_r` does (since Coq 8.5). (2) `+`, `-`, `*`, `++`, `--`, `**`, etc. are called "bullets" and they help you structure your proof into nested subproofs. Subgoals of the same level must have the same bullet sign. E.g. if I have `- destruct ?`, then the nested subgoals cannot start with `-`, see the answer.

Comment: @Sara **(3)** Did you by any chance remove the `-` bullets? This failure could have happened if the `eauto` tactic failed. And `eauto` will fail if you forget adding `Hint Constructors Rules`.

Comment: @"Anton Trunov" Sorry I didn't answer before, I was trying to figure it out but did not succeed. I did not remove the bullets, and I did add Hint. I have `Error: Wrong bullet - : Current bullet - is not finished.` right after eauto, so I think you're right and it's something there that is missing.

Comment: @Sara I've tried running the file with Coq v8.4 and v8.5 -- it works. Here is the [full text](http://pastebin.com/pfzg4Mb0) of what I'm running.

Comment: @"Anton Trunov" I had a couple of little things going on there that were interfering, but I finally figured it out, thank you so much for your help. I've learned a few neat tricks here! I'll keep on proving things :)

Comment: Hi, I kept on working and bumped then bumped into another problem, similar to the previous one. I Edited it on the main question, could you please give me a nudge towards the right direction please? I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @Sara Have a look at [this](http://pastebin.com/JJhux0ZH). I've refactored the theory and added some comments on it. Hope this helps.

Comment: @"Anton Trunov", thank you. I've made a function to send my strings to lists and back so I can keep the original structure too. I didn't use exactly the program you made, but between that one and the original example I think I'm on the right path. I can't thank you enough for all your help and the Coq techniques you've shown me!